# Why is this Smarty if statement always evaluating true?

Tags: php, smarty, smarty2

This:

```
{1234|count_characters}
```

Outputs:

```
4
```

Good. But this:

```
{if 12345|count_characters == 4}
    it's 4
{/if}
```

outputs `it's 4`. The above if statement should evaluate to false obviously. Why is it always evaluating true?

The `count_characters` smarty modifier simply shows the number of characters in a string or number:

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.count.characters.tpl

Comment: Because the `{x|y}` syntax is a smarty shortcode for `echo y(x)`.... where `echo` is significant.... however, `{if y|x ==4 }` is the equivalent of performing bitwise `or` (`|`) on `x` and `y` (12345|count_characters is true because `12345` is true), comparing the result of that operation against `4` (true == 4 with loose-typing), and then if true, etc

Comment: @MarkBaker Ok so now I did this: `{if (12345|count_characters) == 4}it's 4{/if}` and it no longer evaluates as true, good, but neither does this now `{if (1234|count_characters) == 4}it's 4{/if}`. Any example of how this should be done? -Thanks

Comment: To do what you want with smarty, enable PHP in templates or switch to a different templating engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `{x|y}` syntax is a smarty shortcode for `echo y(x)`.... where `echo` is significant

However, `{if y|x ==4 }` is the equivalent of performing bitwise `or` (`|`) on `x` and `y` (`12345|count_characters` is true because `12345` is true, even though `count_characters` would be tested as a constant and if the constant doesn't exist then as a string literal, while throwing a notice), comparing the result of that operation against `4` (true == 4 with loose-typing), and then if true, etc

Answer (score 0):

Smarty is not a programming language; it is a templating markup language. You have taken an output filter and tried to use it as a general-purpose function in a condition. That's not going to work.

You should keep such logic in the PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how you use it.

If in PHP you assign this var:

```
 $smarty->assign('var',12345);
```

And use this code (one extra if to make sure it works as it should):

```
{if $var|count_characters == 4}
    it's 4
{elseif $var|count_characters == 5}
    it's 5
{/if}
```

you will get as output `it's 5` - as it should be.

If you don't assign anything in PHP but assign it in Smarty as in the following code:

```
{assign var="var" value="12345"}

{if $var|count_characters == 4}
    it's 4
{elseif $var|count_characters == 5}
    it's 5
{/if}
```

you will get `it's 5` - as it should be.

As @MarkBaker mentioned when you used `12345|count_characters` the code is evaluated at bitwise operator, the function `count_characters` here is in fact not a function - it's never launched, you can write here anything you want, for example:

```
{if 12345|count_charact87172368716832ers == 4}
    it's 4
{/if}
```

and you will get `it's 4` even if obviously there is no `count_charact87172368716832ers` modifier.

To make it work as you would like you should either assign variable in PHP (as I showed in first code) or assign variable in Smarty (as I showed in second code) or use `count_characters` modifier on string and not on int:

```
{if '12345'|count_characters == 4}
    it's 4
{elseif '12345'|count_characters == 5}
    it's 5
{/if}
```

this code will work as expected - you will get `it's 5`